# WPF Issue with Tab Navigation

Tags: wpf, tabs, navigation

I have control template which is here:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DialogWindowTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type w:DialogWindow}">
    <Border d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="700" CornerRadius="5" Background="{StaticResource ContrastWhiteBrush}"
        BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ContentNormalBrush}">
        <Grid>

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0">
                <Button Content="{TemplateBinding ActionName}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"  KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0" Padding="5,0,5,0" FontWeight="Bold" Height="30" Width="75"
                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ActionCommand}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Static loc:Controls.Dialog_Or}" Style="{StaticResource ContentNormalFontStyle}"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0"/>
                <Button Style="{StaticResource CancelButtonStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,10,0" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                    Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CancelCommand}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

This is .cs file

```
 public DialogWindow()
    {
        // load the template
        ResourceDictionary rd = new ResourceDictionary();
        rd.Source = new Uri(TEMPLATE_URI);
        this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(rd);
        this.Template = this.Resources["DialogWindowTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
        this.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
        this.AllowsTransparency = true;
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(ApplicationCommands.Close, CloseCommandHandler));
        this.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(_escCommand, CloseCommandHandler));
    }
```

**My issue is : I tried all possible options but Tab Navigation does not work for those Buttons. But when I press Ctrl + Tab then it works. I tried this KeyBoard.ControlTabNavigation = "None" also. but It doesn't work.**

Thanks

Comment: Is IsTabStop="True" set on the buttons in the style ButtonStyle?

Comment: I tried that too but it's still the same